Identify user using a secondary attribute (not User ID)
I'm working on Jira OnPremise and I've been asked to study different possibilities regarding authentication. The existing instance is populated by ADFS through an LDAP connection and the authentication is delegated to the AD. I'm currently wondering about the following implementation:

User provisioning through Microsoft AD (OnPrem) (already set)
Delegated authentication through Azure AD
Users from Microsoft AD are synced with Azure AD (already set)

The reason why I don't want to be directly provisioned by Azure AD is that in Azure AD you can have multiple groups with the same name but not in Jira, which is quite a mess to manage.
Now the problem is that currently, the usernames for my AD-provisioned Jira users are not their email addresses. It's a different attribute (I don't know which one but it looks like n_surname).
SO I'm wondering how the SAML assertion, created through the user authentication via their email address, could match the username in Jira, given the attribute used in Jira may not be known by Azure AD. The only thing I'm sure of is that both Azure AD and Jira know the email address, so I'd like to tell the client (Jira), once they receive the token, to match the user with the same email address as given in the SAML assertion.
Do you think it's possible?
Best regards,
Simon
